# Due to huge images. Can we generalize flow_from_directory method for regression problem (CNN): input image and output is x,y (float)

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, regression, tf.keras

Data is in a CSV file which includes image path and target (x and y). where x and y belong to [-1 to 1] after scale
(in keras becasue there are so many image . I can not load all in X_train like normal). Thank you so much for help!
[data in csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgD8l.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write here as the comment section is getting bigger and bigger.

You can try to train the model using gradientTape. For details, please check [here](https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/03/23/using-tensorflow-and-gradienttape-to-train-a-keras-model/). With. that you will have more control over batches.

```
EPOCHS_start = 1
EPOCHS_end = 32

nb_train_steps = training_generator.n // BS

# whatever loss you want to use
loss_fn = BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
train_acc_metric1 = BinaryAccuracy()

for epoch in range(EPOCHS_start, EPOCHS_end):
  print("Start of epoch %d" % (epoch,))
  start_time = time.time()
  loss_total = tf.Variable(0.0)

  # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
  for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(training_generator):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      x_batch_train_scaled = rescale_img(x_batch_train)
      # you have to create your model before
      logits = model(x_batch_train_scaled, training=True)
      y_batch_train = \ 
           np.asarray(y_batch_train).astype('float32').reshape((-1, 1))

      loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)
      print("loss value :  %.4f " % loss_value)

      grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
      optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))

      loss_total = loss_total + loss_value

      # Update training metric.
      train_acc_metric1.update_state(y_batch_train, logits)

      if step >= nb_train_steps:
        # we need to break the loop by hand because
        # the generator loops indefinitely
        break

      # Display metrics at the end of each epoch.
      train_acc = train_acc_metric1.result()


      print("Training acc over epoch: ", \ 
            "%.4f - %.4f - LOSS: %.4f ** Time taken: %.2fs" % \
            (float(train_acc), \ 
            float(loss_total.numpy() / nb_train_steps), \
            (time.time() - start_time)))

      train_acc_metric1.reset_states()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to organise your csv file a bit. Put all the images into a folder (path_to_images), separate the Pixelxy column into 2 columns as px and py. Then,

```
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


train_samples = {'imageID':['a.png','b.png','c.png','d.png'],'px':[23,22,21,24], 'py':[11,12,13,14]}
train_samples = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(train_samples)

path_to_images = 'images/'

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=(1.0 / 255))

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        train_samples,
        x_col='imageID',
        y_col=['px', 'py'],
        directory=path_to_images,
        target_size=(128, 128),
        batch_size=2,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=42,
        class_mode='multi_output')

for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_generator):

    print(y_batch_train[0])
    print(y_batch_train[1])
    break
```

iterate over image batches with multiple outputs. I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you write more about how to train with (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in CNN code? I understand that but i only know the simple way which is loading all image in numpy and training. That why my computer can not run because Memory goes back to ~ zero and  the process is killed.

Comment: df = pd.read_csv("/home/rc/Desktop/*/dataframe2.csv")
filenames = df['NewID'] 
pixelX = df['PixX']

Comment: from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_x,test_x,train_y,test_y=train_test_split(df['NewID'] , df['PixX'], test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

train_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','steer'])
train_df['id'] = train_x
train_df['steer'] = train_y

test_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','steer'])
test_df['id'] = test_x
test_df['steer'] = test_y
images_dir = '/home/rc/Desktop/*/allExperiment/'

Comment: train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255) 
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train_df, directory=images_dir, 
                                              x_col="id", y_col="steer", 
                                              class_mode="raw", target_size=(224, 224), 
                                              batch_size=64)

Comment: test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255) 
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=test_df, directory=images_dir, 
                                              x_col="id", y_col="steer",
                                              class_mode="raw", target_size=(224, 224), 
                                              batch_size=64)

Comment: above is my code for my dataset. But when i train, it does not work properly.

Comment: It is not clear what you are saying here sorry. Once you have the x_batch_train and y_batch_train, you can call model.fit(x_batch_train, y_batch_train, epochs=3).

Comment: Thank you somuch for your help. I wil try it.

Comment: Thank you so much quasimodo. It works. However, when i use model.fit(train_generator, epochs=2, validation_data=valid_generator).it caused deprecation.
as i know when we use fit_generator, we do not need to use "steps_per_epochs" nad "validation_steps". Am I right ?

Comment: Another thing is when I use your way " model.fit(x_batch_train, y_batch_train, epochs=3)".

Comment: history=model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_sizeee),
steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epochss,
epochs=epochssss,
validation_steps=(x_val, y_val, batch_size=batch_sizeee))

Above code is correct ?